# Undefined reference to `_sbrk' when building Pebble watchapp

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Sometimes my Pebble watchapp rejects to build giving an unfriendly error message:

```
$ pebble build
[...]
[ 9/13] cprogram: build/src/project_lift.c.7.o build/appinfo.auto.c.7.o -> build/pebble-app.elf
/Users/Pavlo/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0.1/arm-cs-tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb2/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
/Users/thomas/work/arm-eabi-toolchain/build/newlib/arm-none-eabi/thumb2/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../newlib-2012.09/newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:60: undefined reference to `_sbrk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have nothing to do with `sbrkr.c` directly. I've figured out that this is caused by the particular line of code in my app. Can I get more concise error message (like a callstack, maybe)?

Comment: The answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812983/how-to-find-c-language-constructs-allocating-dynamic-memory is useful. Add --cref option to ld and check the map file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to link to a function that is not supported by pebble like `printf`, `sprintf`, `fopen`, etc. Make sure the function you are calling are listed in Pebble api docs.

Comment: Looks like you're right. How did you find out? Personal experience?

Comment: @sarfata I have this same issue and have searched my code base repeatedly for any sign of these functions or any of them in `pebble_warn_unsupported_functions.h` and can't find any. Do you have any further advice on how to track down the problematic function?

Comment: You can always use dichotomy to find the source of your problem: comment out large portions of your program (or remove them completely) until it builds and then start adding back until it breaks. Eventually you will find the culprit!