# How to find C++ language constructs allocating dynamic memory?

Tags: c++, embedded

I work on an embedded system firmware code-basis which currently uses dynamic memory allocation. Now, all dynamic memory allocation shall be removed for reliability reasons.

As a first step, I removed the _sbrk syscall implementation, such that all dynamic allocations fail to link. Since I compile with -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections and link with -Wl,--gc-sections I expect the link step to complete as long as no dynamic memory allocation occurs. (This worked for me in past C projects, unsure about C++ here.)

Although the following linker error message is expected, it does not help to find the C++ construct which triggers the dynamic allocation.

```
[...]arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there an effective way to find C++ language constructs, which use dynamic heap allocation (apart from the obvious use of *new*)?

**EDIT**: I am looking for a static tool, not a runtime instrumentation/analysis technique.

**EDIT2**: (Since somebody removed the appropriate tags:) The project targets an STM32F4 MCU and is compiled and linked with an GCC-based arm-none-eabi-* toolchain.

Comment: @Ron Correct, these are the tricky parts. I am looking for a way to get error messages or warnings pointing to concrete occurrences of such constructs in my code basis. e.g. during compilation or by static analysis etc.

Comment: Why do you have a sbrk system call on an embedded systems? That one rather suggests that you have something Linux-ish, PC-like.

Comment: @Lundin The target is an STM32F4 and _sbrk is simply the way of newlib to allocate memory. What else would you expect in this context?

Comment: I would have expected that the library handles the allocation by itself. But instead it apparently does some smelly "system" calls. As for which function that triggered the _sbrk call, it appears to be _sbrk_r, so probably you haven't killed off this library in a clean way. There may be functions in the same translation unit as _sbrk which calls it, even if those functions in turn aren't used by the application.

Comment: @Lundin : In newlib `_sbrk` is a user supplied syscall in order to be able to adapt it to hosted and non-hosted environments of various kinds.  sbrk does not do the actual allocation or heap management, it just provides data to the heap manager.  A minimal implementation for standalone systems is defined at https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls

Comment: What do you think just removing the actual memory allocation function help? If you want to remove all dynamic allocation, you have to restructure the whole code.

Comment: @Clifford Yeah I understand that, hence "smelly". It suggests that there might be lots of code present which was actually written with a hosted system in mind.

Comment: @Olaf Sure, this question is about finding the pieces which need to be rewritten/refactored. By removing sbrk I ensure at link-time that no nasty bits  of C++ inject an unwanted allocation, because in such a case linking will fail. However, this does not help to find the actual cause of the allocation; hence this question.

Comment: @Alexander: That's not the correct way, as I wrote. Maybe you overread the word "restructure".

Comment: @Olaf: This technique [theoretically] identifies the areas of code that will need first restructuring. Then you take that knowledge that use it to decide how much more of the project should be restructured as a result. You appear to be suggesting that the OP should just do it "blind", which basically means rewriting the project from scratch.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't consider going through the full source and - yes - major rewrites **after** the documented architecture  has be rewritten to a suitable one "blindly". The approach as shown now typically results in aprticular modifications which most times leaves a patchwork of modification behind.

Comment: @Olaf :  He is not suggesting that that is the correct way.  Removing `sbrk` will prove or otherwise that there is no heap dependencies in the code; however it does not locate the user code that is causing the dependency - that is what he is asking.

Comment: Can you build newlib with `-DMALLOC_PROVIDED` and link against that?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with blocking linkage to sbrk is that sbrk is the very bottom of the heap management process and is not necessarily called for all allocations.  It is simply a means of adding to the existing heap pool.

The `new` operator may be overloaded, or placement-new, so need not even perform dynamic allocation or allocation via the system heap. However instances of `new` that do will at least call `malloc()`.

The GNU linker `--cref` output may help; this will tell you for each symbol, what files reference them.  Unfortunately the GNU linker does not have the `--callgraph` option that the ARM linker has, which will show the complete call path that leads to any particular function.

Avoiding explicit linkage of dynamic memory allocation probably means removing most of the C++ specific parts of the standard library - certainly STL container classes, `std::string`.

Comment: This is a (long) comment on the question, you provide no answer.

Comment: @YSC - the `--cref` suggestion is a partial answer.  It is unsatisfactory because it will only narrow down to the object module level.  The ARM linker will narrow it down to the function-call level.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an effective way to find C++ language constructs, which use dynamic heap allocation?

Yes there is: massif.

Massif is a memory profiler which will enable you to pinpoint where memory is allocated in your code base. With such a listing, you can change all incriminated code and check again there is no dynamic allocation left.

From [Massif (valgrind) documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) :

> Massif is a heap profiler. It measures how much heap memory your program uses. [...] Importantly, Massif tells you not only how much heap memory your program is using, it also gives very detailed information that indicates which parts of your program are responsible for allocating the heap memory.
>
> By default, Massif does not measure [lower-level system calls used directly to allocate memory] However, if you wish to measure *all* the memory used by your program, you can use the `--pages-as-heap=yes`.

Since you work on embedded system, it might make massif work with your code base a bit difficult; but it is possible, either by having a linux/windows port or by having massif running on your specific target.

Comment: Runtime profiling is all very well, but the question is about ensuring no code using dynamic memory allocation is linked and where it is  finding out which code is doing the dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Clifford As quoted, massif enables you to pinpoint where your program allocates memory. From OP: _"Now, all dynamic memory allocation shall be removed for reliability reasons."_ This means massif would be a suitable tool to remove all dynamic allocations from their code base. The linking you're talking about is merely a first solution OP envisaged.

Comment: @YSC Thanks for the idea. A simpler dynamic solution is to simply put a breakpoint at the sbrk function. However, this approach is infeasible, because intensive stimulation of the embedded system would be required to run all states of the code. This is an impossible endeavor even for small systems. Hence, I edited the question to ask for static analysis techniques.

Comment: @YSC : It is a runtime check.  It will only detect allocations that occur during execution - unless you run a test with 100% code coverage, it will not detect all allocations.  It may detect most of them.  That said getting a tool intended for a hosted environment working on a non hosted environment would be an issue.  The non-hosted environment has no process model or loader - the code is normally a single monolithic link.  Moreover I would not be surprised if the tool itself included dynamic memory allocation.